# cout variable value delay

Tags: c++, pointers, delay, cout

```
int * getInt2(int a[]) {
    (*a) *= 2;
    return a;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int intInit = 1;
    int * (*intPtr)(int *) = getInt2;
    cout << intInit++ << ":" << intInit << endl;
    cout << intPtr(&intInit) << ":" << intInit<<endl;
    cout << intInit << endl;
    cout << *intPtr(&intInit) << endl;
    cout << (*intPtr)(&intInit) << ":" << *(*intPtr)(&intInit) << endl;
    cout << intInit << endl;
}
```

real result when running:

```
1:2
012FFABC:2
4
8
012FFABC:16
32
```

but I expect it to be:

```
1:2
012FFABC:4
4
8
012FFABC:32
32
```

what did i misunderstand?Is there any reason why it is delayed? thanks for any clue.

I see someone think the expression behaviour is undefined in c++ and the focus is always in auto-increment operation,so I add an example:

```
int addTarget(int &n) {
    n += 1;
    return n;
}
int multiplyTarget(int &n) {
    n *= 2;
    return n;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int intTest = 1;
    cout << multiplyTarget(intTest) << ":" << addTarget(intTest) << endl;
    cout << addTarget(intTest) << ":" << multiplyTarget(intTest) << endl;
}
```

above code's result is:

```
4:2
9:8
```

I see someone say that the output sequence is from left to right and the operation sequence is from right to me.this can explain most situation.but I think the first example's first output should be 1:1 not 1:2 according to this theory.I really want to know the theory.

Comment: this code is running in visual studio 15.9.9 

.net framework 4.7.03190

Comment: What do you mean by "delayed" in this context?

Comment: I obtain the expected result on Fedora 29, x86_64. No sanitizer or Valgrind findings.

Comment: I did, too - Visual Studio 2017 15.9.5 on all configuration modes.

Comment: why is your example so complicated? The ony difference in output seems to be from incrementing/multiplying an `int` , why pointers or even function pointers?

Comment: I struggled to find the right google terms but finally I found what I was looking for. I strongly believe your mis-understanding comes from not considering what's explained here: [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). You may scroll down to [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) and will find that some of your expressions are quite similar. ;-) It's not quite easy to puzzle out what's undefined, what unspecified, and for which standard. I wouldn't use such things in productive code.

Comment: One of your examples was especially eye-catching to me: `cout << intInit++ << ":" << intInit << endl;` I tried on coliru and got (for my suprise) the same result like you. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81fa9c4b7588f176) On the other hand, the warning `operation on 'intInit' may be undefined` didn't surprise me. ;-)

Comment: delayed mean the same as delayed variable in windows batch programming,this is only learning code,not in productive env.

Comment: Why using undefined behavior results in undefined behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before C++17,

```
std::cout << intInit++ << ":" << intInit << endl;
```

the increment of `intInit` doesn't have to happen before next `<<`

so both

```
std::cout << intInit << ":" << intInit << endl; intInit++;
```

or

```
std::cout << intInit;
intInit++;
std::cout << ":" << intInit << endl; intInit++;
```

are valid.

In C++17, full side effect of `intInit++` should happen before `std::cout << ":" << intInit << endl`.

Comment: I add a new example in my question.

Comment: do you mean ```std::cout << intInit;
intInit++
std::cout << ":" << intInit << endl;```

Answer (score 0):

It is like function parse input parameters,calculate from right to left,then push the value into stack and show the value.for example:

```
int add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
auto i = 0;
add(i++, i, ++i);
```

we get 5 at last.but if it is calculated first and then push the value into stack,I still think the first input should be 1:1 not 1:2.but when I change the compiler standard to c++ 17. the result of code above is 3.I change the original code to be:

```
    int intInit = 1;
    int * (*intPtr)(int *) = getInt2;
    cout << intInit++ << ":" << intInit << endl;
    cout << *intPtr(&intInit) << ":" << intInit<<endl;
    cout << intInit << endl;
    cout << *intPtr(&intInit) << endl;
    //(* ptr)函数书写
    cout << *(*intPtr)(&intInit) << ":" << *(*intPtr)(&intInit) << endl;
    cout << intInit << endl;
```

and the output is normal:

```
1:2
4:4
4
8
16:32
32
```

It is really related to c++ standard and the c++ 14 compiler may be not good at parameter parsing.

Comment: Prior c++17, `add(i++, i, ++i);` was UB, after it is order sequence is undertermined.